# Perturbation theory of the eigenvalues about a symmetric matrix: Reality of Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, perturbation-theory

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix, and let $E$ be a real matrix. Is it true that if the perturbation matrix $E$ is small in some norm, then the eigenvalues of $\hat A := A+E$ are all real? What if we have more properties on $A$ and $E$: $A$ is diagonalizable and $E$ is skew symmetric?

**Note:** 
I have seen two interesting lines of discussions on the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix with perturbation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1077629/567412) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1079423/567412), but there is no discussion on the ***reality*** of eigenvalues.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you lookes at examples like :$$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0  \\
       0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$and
$$E=
        \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & \epsilon  \\
       - \epsilon & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Going beyond Keith's excellent example, it doesn't matter what $A$ is, there are always going to be matrices arbitrarily close to $A$ with non-real eigenvalues. This is pretty much because the reals have no interior as a subset of the complex numbers, so all real numbers are approached by non-reals.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent example and the excellent intuition!